# Periodically sync cardholders/object from Protege GX to XProtect

Tags: milestone, protege-gx

I'm developing a plugin to integrate with Protege GX.

I need to sync cardholders, objects every hour. The result should be like clicking button "Refresh Configuration" in XProtect Managementimage. Is there any way that we can do it?
[refresh configuration button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4FO9.png)

I've been looking at the document and found this method: `StartFetchConfiguration()`

https://doc.developer.milestonesys.com/html/index.html?base=mipachelp/class_video_o_s_1_1_platform_1_1_access_control_1_1_plugin_1_1_a_c_configuration_manager.html&tree=tree_search.html?search=startfetchconfiguration

Should this function work for this case?

Use the plugin to periodically fetch Protege GX objects and save to XProtect.